# Custom thumbnail size of image when uploaded

Tags: images

I'm trying to make a custom thumbnail size when I upload an image only for GIFs. How do I get the `image_path`?

```
list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $image_path );    
$thumbWidth = $width - 10 ;
$thumbhHeight = $height - 10;
if ( $type == 1 ) {
    add_image_size( 'new-size', $thumbWidth, $thumbhHeight, true ); //(cropped)
}

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_image_sizes' );
function my_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    $addsizes = array(
        "new-size" => __( "New Size")
    );
    $newsizes = array_merge( $sizes, $addsizes );
    return $newsizes;
}
```